# Java Audioclip: new AudioClip(s) with remote URL creates UI lags

Tags: java, javafx

Using `new AudioClip(s)` with `s` an external UI String will download the clip from a remote server. This can take several seconds.

If this is done on the JavaFX Application thread, the application will likely become unresponsive.

What is the preferred solution to prevent this long download from being on the JavaFX App thread?

Example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        AudioClip sound = new AudioClip("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qq8vvfqx2l8sljb/Dice%201.wav?dl=0");
        System.out.println("Time taken (ms): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(), 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Creating the `AudioClip` this way freezes the JavaFX thread for around 2-3 seconds on my computer.

Comment: load in background thread ..

Comment: So AudioClip doesn't need to be initialized in the JavaFX Application thread?

Comment: don't know to be  honest - but it's not part of the scenegraph and loading at least should be fine anyway

Answer (score 1):

any operation that is expected to take more than some milliseconds needs to be moved out of the JavaFX Application Thread, because otherwise, it will freeze your UI until it's done, if I were to load an audio file from a remote URL I would do it in a new Thread as follows :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane(new ProgressIndicator());

        Button play = new Button("play");

        Task<AudioClip> loadAudio = new Task<AudioClip>() {
            @Override
            protected AudioClip call() throws Exception {
                return new AudioClip("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qq8vvfqx2l8sljb/Dice%201.wav?dl=0");
            }
        };

        loadAudio.setOnSucceeded(successEvent -> {
            play.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
                try {
                    loadAudio.get().play();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException x) {
                    //Handle Exceptions
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            root.getChildren().setAll(play);
        });

        new Thread(loadAudio).start();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Note that in some cases, your app will need to indicate to the users that it is doing something in the background and they will need to wait until the operation is done, in this example I used a simple progress indicator while the audio is being downloaded from the remote URL.

note: I edited the solution using Task (the previous version works fine as well as this version as I have tested)

Comment: `sound` should be `volatile` if you want to do it like this. This looks like a good use-case for a `Task<AudioClip>`.

Comment: @James_D I'm not sure `volatile` is strictly necessary here; I would expect the call to `runLater` to create the necessary _happens-before_ relationship (though the documentation makes no such guarantee I fail to see how it could be implemented without creating a _happens-before_ relationship between the background thread and the FX thread).

Comment: @Slaw I think in practice it's almost certainly unnecessary, because the optimization the JVM would need to make would be incredibly complex. There's a happens-before relationship between setting the value of `sound` and adding the `play` button to the UI, but I don't think that's technically enough. (Moving `play.setOnAction(...)` to the `Platform.runLater(...)` would probably be enough too...?). Of course, using a `Task` means we don't have to think about all this... which is precisely why it's better to use the higher-level API.

Comment: @James_D The `onAction` handler doesn't capture the `sound` field but rather the enclosing instance of `App` (i.e. `App.this.sound`). So I believe the Java Memory Model guarantees that the FX thread will see the latest value in the above example, regardless of any optimizations the JVM may or may not make. If I'm not mistaken, this is why fields don't have to be (effectively) final when used in lambdas/anonymous classes—they have defined behavior in a multi-threaded environment, unlike local variables (plus heap vs stack). But all that said, I agree `Task` would make things easier/clearer.